# How to download few files in iphone via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, download

I have a website where user can download few files automatically. I did it using JS, that creates few hidden iframe tags:

```
<iframe src="/path/to/file1.jpg" />
<iframe src="/path/to/file2.zip" />
<iframe src="/path/to/file3.exe" />
```

The response has `content-disposition: attachment` header.

This works in PC browsers, but don't work in iPhone. Is there a method to download few files in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not allow File Download on iPhone. So (is the iPhone is not jailbreaked) you have no Chance.

You could only display Images (in Browser) and save them locally on your Phone.